# How to prove that $A - (A \cap B) = A - B$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I've found a very [similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1913409/prove-that-a-a-b-a-cap-b-by-use-set-properties), but couldn't follow the only answer. I don't know how to get this: $A\cap(A^c\cup B)=(A\cap A^c)\cup (A\cap B)$, even if I see that they're equivalent.

I want to know how to prove this using set properties as $A \cap A' = 0$, $(A \cap B)\cap C = A \cap    (B \cap C)$, $A \cap \varnothing = \varnothing$, $A \cup \varnothing = A$,  if that's possible.

I can usually think with Venn diagrams and get the answer, especially because of the visual intuition, but they can't be used to prove anything and they won't get me far anyway. I understand that $A - (A \cap B) = A - B$, my problem is in proving it.

Comment: I would avoid using complements to prove these since that would require that we assume the existence of a universal set that contains both $A$ and $B$ as subsets.  Such an assumption is unnecessary however.  Use instead $A\setminus B = \{x~:~x\in A~\text{and}~x\notin B\}$

Comment: As for how to get from $A\cap (A^c\cup B)=(A\cap A^c)\cup (A\cap B)$.,  this follows from the distributivity of intersection over union.  You should know that $E\cap (F\cup G) = (E\cap F)\cup (E\cap G)$.  You should similarly know that $E\cup (F\cap G)= (E\cup F)\cap (E\cup G)$.  You should also know $(E\cap F)^c = E^c\cup F^c$ and similarly $(E\cup F)^c = E^c \cap F^c$ and $E\setminus F = E\cap F^c$ (*assuming the existence of a valid universal set*)  This properties along with those you mentioned in your post are all you should need.

Comment: Thank you! I forgot about the distributivity one. And yes, this is assuming the existence of a universal set.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It *can* be done with the algebraic properties of set operations, but I think the simplest, most self-evident proof is to just take an unknown element of each side, and show that it's an element of the other side.

Here's a proof based on that approach . . .

First we show the inclusion $A - (A \cap B) \subseteq A - B$.

- Let $x\in A - (A \cap B)$.$\\[4pt]$

  Then $x\in A$, but $x\notin A\cap B$.$\\[4pt]$

  Since $x\notin A\cap B$, $x$ is not in *both* $A$ and $B$.$\\[4pt]$

  Hence, since $x\in A$, it follows that $x\notin B$.$\\[4pt]$

  Thus, $x\in A$, but $x\notin B$, so $x\in  A - B$.

It follows $A - (A \cap B) \subseteq A - B$.

Next we show the inclusion $A - B\subseteq A - (A \cap B)$.

- Let $x\in A - B$.$\\[4pt]$

  Then $x\in A$, but $x\notin B$.$\\[4pt]$

  Since $x\notin B$, $x\notin A\cap B$.$\\[4pt]$

  Thus, $x\in A$, but $x\notin A\cap B$, so $x\in  A - (A\cap B)$.$\\[4pt]$

It follows $A - B\subseteq A - (A \cap B)$.

Since we have both inclusions, it follows that $A - (A \cap B)=A - B$, as was to be shown.

Comment: It's nice to see another way to do this. So you're assuming that $A - (A \cap B) \subseteq A - B$ (and also $A - B\subseteq A - (A \cap B)$) is true, then proving it?

Comment: I certainly don't _assume_ what I'm trying to prove. Rather, I _state_ what I'm trying to prove, and then proceed to prove it. Given sets $S,T$, to prove $S\subseteq T$, it suffices to show that $x\in S$ implies $x\in T$. Thus, to prove $S\subseteq T$, we can start by assuming $x\in S$, and then show, using that assumption, that we must have $x\in T$.

Comment: Something like this actually was on my test today (Show that $B-A \subseteq (A \cup B) - A$). I didn't get it right, but I managed to conclude that $x \in B$, $x \notin A$, $x \notin B \cap A$, $x \in B - A$. Your demonstration definitely helped, though.

Comment: @AtAn: To prove $B-A\subseteq (A\cup B)-A$, the idea is to show if $x\in B-A$, then $x\in(A\cup B)-A$. Here's a proof along those lines: Assume $x\in B-A$. Then $x\in B$, but $x\notin A$. Since $x\in B$, we get $x\in A\cup B$. Hence, since $x\in A\cup B$, and $x\notin A$, we get $x\in (A\cup B)-A$. Therefore $B-A\subseteq (A\cup B)-A$.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an algebraic like proof you seemed to want
instead of a point by point proof.

A - (A $\cap$ B) = A $\cap (A \cap B)^c$ =
$A \cap (A^c \cup B^c)$ =
$(A \cap A^c) \cup (A \cap B^c) = A \cap B^c = A - B.$

Notice the use of DeMorgan's rules for sets.